# Function signature doesn't match called function, difference between const char[] and char*?

Tags: c++, android-wifi

I am using PubSubClient.h, as defined here: https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api.html

The instance is created as the following:

```
WiFiClientSecure secureCl;
PubSubClient mqttCl(secureCl);
```

PubSubClient has method called **setCallBack**, which takes in the parameter **callback**.

> PubSubClient setCallback (callback)
>
> callback : a pointer to a message callback function called when a message arrives for a subscription created by this client.

The following signature is given for function **callback**:

```
void callback(const char[] topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length)
```

But, within the example code I were given, inside setup the callback function used is the receivedCallback function:

```
mqttCl.setCallback(receivedCallback); //called inside setup()
```

And the function is given as:

```
void receivedCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
//some code here

}
```

Now, I can see that it has `char*` topic, instead of `const char[]` and I can't get my head around how it is not const char[], as defined by the signature. Could someone explain in simple terms why is it like that?

Comment: That's simply a bug. `const char[]` and `const char*` are the same in that context, but without the `const` it's something different and it's not compatible.

Comment: The documentation is wrong. The code on github uses `#define MQTT_CALLBACK_SIGNATURE void (*callback)(char*, uint8_t*, unsigned int)`

Comment: have you checked if the documentation corresponds to the same version of binaries? may be it is a different version, so a different signature. do you try a dump of binaries to see available functions ? **dumpbin  /EXPORTS "....\yourlib.dll"**

Answer (score 0):

It seems a **bug**, in this context the problem is given by the `const` attribute e not by the `[]` or the `*`. In fact `const char[]` and `const char*` are equal, also `char[]` and `char*` are equal, but `const char[]` and `char*` can create something that **is incompatible**.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the missing `const` of your callback.
Basically `char* topic` as an argument means that you are allowed to manipulate the content of `topic` as in `topic[0] = 'A';`.
On the other side `const char*` or `const char[]` guarantees that there will not be a change to the underlying string and so a pointer to an string from the read-only memory could be given.

`mqttCl` could for example do the following:

```
byte payload[10];
callback("test-topic", payload, 10);
```

And your `recievedCallback` is allowed to do:

```
topic[0] = 'b';
```

The compiler is allowed to store `"test-topic"` in the read-only memory of the process in which case the program would crash. To prevent this the `const` part in type signatures must match.